# How can I open an .hta file automatic in fullscreen?

Tags: html, css, hta

I have an .hta file but everytime I run it open in a small screen. Can I run it in fullscreen like any other nav?

Comment: Welcome. SO is a coding site. Configuring software not normally used for programming is outside our scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the HTA to always open maximized, add an `hta:application` section with `wimdowstate=maximize`. If you want the user to be able to maximize the HTA window, remove options from that section that are suppressing the caption and/or maximize button. See the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms536495(v=vs.85)) for more details.